# Testing for data-no-turbolink in body tag with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How do you test for the presence of `data-no-turbolink` in a body tag in an rspec request spec?  For example if the home page has
`<body data-no-turbolink>` declaration
I would like to do a test like

```
it 'home page should disable all links for turbolinks' do
  visit '/'
  response.should have_selector('body', data-no-turbolink)
end
```

However the above test causes a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix the Capybara matchers into RSpec without actually using 'visit', to make request specs work in roughly the same way as feature specs:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec/matchers'
include Capybara::RSpecMatchers

describe "doing stuff", type: :request do
  it 'home page should have turbolink disabled' do
    get "http://localhost:3000/home/index"
    expect(response.body).to have_selector('body[data-no-turbolink]')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As a feature spec:

```
# spec/features/stuff_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe "doing stuff", type: :feature do
  it 'home page should have turbolink disabled' do
    visit '/'
    expect(page).to have_selector('body[data-no-turbolink]')
  end
end
```

Comment: This is useful, so I have upvoted it, but still hoping someone can give the corresponding answer for requests spec.

Comment: A request spec should work the same way. Try changing `type: :feature` to `type: :request` and see.

Comment: @zetetic: I believe this relates to the [differences](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/Capybara.md#user-content-upgrading-to-capybara-20) between feature and request specs.